# Double value in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double, decimal

**Sample Example:**

```
var amount = 100; 
alert(amount);  // output: 100
```

How can i achieve output as `100.0`?

Comment: You can use amount.toFixed(1) to get an output with one dp

Comment: If you set a float, you'll get one https://jsfiddle.net/e9dgqtb2/

Comment: @dougajmcdonald, should post that as an answer.

Comment: @SatejS This is just a sample example,, actually i am getting many integer numbers from database,, so i need to convert it.. Ex: 99 to 99.0, 56 to 56.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var amount = 100;
alert(amount.toFixed(1));  // output: 100.0
alert(amount.toFixed(2));  // output: 100.00
alert(amount.toFixed(3));  // output: 100.000
```

Comment: What happened? Didn't like my answer.

Comment: @Jai nothing like tat, i really appreciate ur answer.. just added a simple alert answer as similar to question

Answer (score 8):

use `.toFixed(int)`:

```js
var amount = 100;
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(1);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var amount = 100;
alert(amount);  // output: 100
alert(amount.toFixed(1));  // output: 100.0
alert(amount.toFixed(2));  // output: 100.00
alert(amount.toFixed(3));  // output: 100.000
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

```
**number.toFixed(x)**
```

where number is what you intend to convert to double, and X is the precision you want to set.